# Get Apple NVRAM values using Swift

Tags: swift, iokit

Is it possible to retrieve named NVRAM values using Swift and IOKit? Preferably using the available frameworks rather than calling the `nvram` command line utility. Any example code would be helpful, there doesn't seem to be a lot of examples available, especially using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity - https://github.com/hansen-m/NVRAMManager/blob/master/NVRAM.swift

A Swift class I wrote to replicate the basic functionality of `nvram`.

Comment: In case you ever change your code etc., could you edit your question to include the code as well as a description, since the code is somewhat short?